# Spring Cloud Dataflow UI Exception after installation in minikube

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task, spring-cloud-dataflow-ui

Hi I am new to spring cloud dataflow and am trying to install scdf in minikube using the documentation

**https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/installation/kubernetes/kubectl/**

But when dashboard accessed, **"Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection"** exception occurs.
Dashboard appears but when accessing the tabs ,the error message appears.

Hope someone helps.

Comment: Could you check to make sure MySQL is installed and the pod is up and running? Perhaps also verify the `kubectl describe <pod>` of the MySQL and SCDF pods.

Comment: @SabbyAnandan MySQL restarted many times due to low configuration.I resolved it by changing the minikube configuration.Thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mysql container stopped and started for me many times.

I resolved the issue by increasing the cpu and memory of the minikube.

**minikube start --cpus 4 --memory 8192**

The main point is that if you had started minikube earlier without this configuration,you have to delete the minikube and then execute the above command.Then only the configuration gets in effect.

(**minikube stop && minikube start --cpus 4 --memory 8192**    didnot work for me).
To verify the configuration,you can go for **kubectl describe nodes**